# What is the smallest positive binary type number divisible by $225$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A binary type number is an integer (base $10$) with the property that all of its digits are either $0$ or $1$. What is the smallest positive binary type number divisible by $225$.

I dont have too much knowledge on binary numbers so What confuses me about this question is $225$ is not a binary number since a binary number only contains $0$ or $1$. So that binary number must be a multiple of $225$ but there arent any multiples that only contain $0$ and $1$.

So im not sure how to approach this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $225=9\cdot 25$, so the solution must be a multiple of $9$ and a multiple of $25$.  A multiple of $9$ has [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) $9$, so in particular the solution must contain at least nine $1$'s.  Further, a solution must end in $00$, $01$, $10$, or $11$; however only $00$ gives a multiple of $25$.  The combination of these two conditions suggests trying $11111111100$, i.e. nine $1$'s followed by two $0$'s.  In fact this works, and is minimal by the two criteria above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are multiples of $225$ (and all other numbers) that have all their digits $0$ or $1$.  One example, not the smallest, is $111111111111111111000$, which, when divided by $225$ yields $493827160493827160$ with no remainder.

To find the smallest, you need to first find out how many factors of $2$ and $5$ there are and make them equal.  Then you need to find how long a string of $1$'s is needed to deal with the rest of the factors.